# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: home.html

Tags: python, django, templates

django project was working fine! home page and other pages were rendering no problems. I creating products app/ component page and accidentally named "templates" template so i renamed template to "templates" and that when i started have issues.

I ran terminal commands:

- python manage.py makemigrations
- python manage.py migrate
- python collectstatic

Nothing is working!

I am getting an error message:

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: home.html

Comment: Are you referring to the folder "templates"?

Comment: Yes. I named the templates folder in products template rather than templates. So, I renamed the folder templates and now i'm receiving an error message. I've even tried deleting products complete and still receive error message

Answer (score 6):

Try replacing your current 'TEMPLATES' variable in 'settings.py' with this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    },
]
```

Comment: I tried replacing with your code but i'm still receiving the same error message. i'm using pycharm as my editor not sure if that matters.

Comment: Where is template in the file structure? I use PyCharm as well and the one time I did this, I also accidentally moved the folder.

Comment: templates for products is nested in the products directory, whereas templates for home is in ecommerce directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your app should be added to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'name_of_your_app'
]
```